# tkinter копирование содержимого scrolledtext

Tags: python, tkinter

Как скопировать в буфер обмена введённый текст в scrolledtext ?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import scrolledtext

root = Tk()
root.geometry('400x200+600+300')

def copy():
    txt.clipboard_append(txt)

btn = Button(root, text='скопировать', command=copy)
btn.place(x=15, y=15)

txt = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(root, width=33, height=11)
txt.place(x=100, y=10)

root.mainloop()
```

сейчас по клику в буфер копируется >>> !frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`txt` - это сам объект `ScrolledText`. При копировании в буфер обмена у вас попадает `str(txt)`, но это не текстовое содержимое виджета, а имя класса tcl. Чтобы получить из виджета текст, нужно вызвать метод `get` (аналогично объекту `Text` - см. например [Tkinter Text](https://otus.ru/nest/post/1190/)):

```
def copy():
    txt.clipboard_clear()  # Очистить буфер обмена
    txt.clipboard_append(txt.get(1.0, END))  # Скопировать текст в буфер обмена
```

Comment: спасибо за объяснение, работает. только буфер при каждом нажатии дополняется копией содержимого виджета ScrolledText, как сделать чтобы он перезаписывался а не дополнялся?

Comment: @Jimmy, дополнил ответ